# Most useful free Jenkins plugins

Tags: plugins, continuous-integration, jenkins

Jenkins is an extendable open source continuous integration server.

There's a list of plugins available for Jenkins, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins, but which ones have you found the most useful?

**List**:

[Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

[NUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin)

**.NET**

[Thoughts on how to use Jenkins for .NET Builds in a Windows environment.](http://jenkinsheaven.blogspot.com/2011/04/plugins-for-net-builds-part-1.html)

Comment: I'm afraid this will get closed the moment it attracts enough users for this, because it's not a question that allows one, right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and the [NUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin).

We haven't found a need for any other plugin.